# RewriteRule confusion: Pattern also matches existing directory name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried having `http://domain.com/user/foobar` redirected to `http://domain.com/user/index.php?id=foobar` using the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /data
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user/index.php?id=$1
```

But for some reason only *index.php* (not *foobar*) is returned to the script as ID.

I think mod_rewrite gets confused because of the existing folder name also matching the regex pattern. It works, however, after renaming the folder to `_user` and accordingly modifying the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take care that the rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` is applied multiple times:

```
0: http://domain.com/data/user/foobar
1: /data/user/foobar -> /data/user/index.php?id=foobar
2: /data/user/index.php?id=foobar -> /data/user/index.php?id=index.php
```

So it always replaces your `id` parameter with `index.php`.

You need to [write a condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) that if `index.php` is already requested, it won't get rewritten, e.g. by checking if a file already exists:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /data

# the following condition applies to the next rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user/index.php?id=$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /data

#if not index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```